# Google OAuth throws ArgumentNullException when registering new user via Google

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, oauth

In our MVC4 application we used the standard OAuth login control to be able to login with Google. Once a user is logged into Gmail and logins on our website for the first time he is directed to the ExternalLoginConfirmation screen. The user can then choose a username to be associated with this account and submit the form.

The code used to work, but along the way an error was introduced. Now when a new Google user logs in for the first time and clicks on submit after entering a username the following error (plus stacktrace) is thrown:

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: data
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web 
request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where 
it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: data

Source Error:

Line 312:            string providerUserId = null;
Line 313:
Line 314:            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated || 
         !OAuthWebSecurity.TryDeserializeProviderUserId(model.ExternalLoginData, 
         out provider, out providerUserId))
Line 315:            {
Line 316:                return RedirectToAction("Manage");
```

With the following stacktrace: see [this gist for stacktrace](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7527134).

The code blow is the code we use in the ExternalLoginConfirmation controller and is also the standard code:

```
// POST: /Account/ExternalLoginConfirmation

[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult ExternalLoginConfirmation(RegisterExternalLoginModel model, 
     string returnUrl)
{
    string provider = null;
    string providerUserId = null;

    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated ||    
       !OAuthWebSecurity.TryDeserializeProviderUserId(model.
       ExternalLoginData, out provider, out providerUserId))
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Manage");
    }

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Insert a new user into the database
        using ( [project]Context db = new [project]Context())
        {
            User user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Name.ToLower() == 
                 model.UserName.ToLower());
         // Check if user already exists
             if (user == null)
             {
              // Insert name into the profile table
                    user = new User { Name = model.UserName };
                    db.Users.Add(user);
                    db.Schedules.Add(new Schedule { date = DateTime.Now, 
                                 UserId = user.UserId });
                    db.SaveChanges();                   

                    OAuthWebSecurity.CreateOrUpdateAccount(provider, 
                          providerUserId, model.UserName);
                    OAuthWebSecurity.Login(provider, providerUserId, 
                            createPersistentCookie: false);

                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
              }
              else
              {
                   ModelState.AddModelError("UserName", "Username already exists")
              }
          }
      }

      ViewBag.ProviderDisplayName = 
              OAuthWebSecurity.GetOAuthClientData(provider).DisplayName;
              ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
      return View(model);
 }
```

When we look in our version control it shows that we did not make adjustments to the RegisterExternalLoginModel except for changing the errormessage:

```
public class RegisterExternalLoginModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Username is mandatory.")]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string ExternalLoginData { get; set; }
}
```

We would love to solve this issue. We are quite new to C# and MVC so we can use some help! Does anybody has any idea what can be wrong?

(Naturally, if more information is needed we can of course provide it upon request, but since we do not know what is relevant we leave it at this for now.)

**/edit extra info**

User class looks like this:

```
public class User {
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public bool isAvailable { get; set; }
}
```

and four standard OAuth tables are created for webpages_Membership, webpages_OAuthMembership, webpages_Roles and webpages_UsersInRoles.

When debugging we have the following values at the statement that goes wrong:

```
User.Identity: System.Security.Principal.GenericIdentity
User.Identity.IsAuthenticated: false
model: RegisterExternalLoginModel
model.ExternalLoginData: null
provider: null
providerUserId: null
this: Controllers.AccountController
```

Comment: What does your User Profile class look like? Also when you step into your code, right before the error, so you see null variables?

Comment: You have a chunk (the important bit) missing from your `ExternalLoginConfirmation` example. Can you show the rest of that method?

Comment: your `ExternalLoginConfirmation` method should have a part beginning with `if(ModelState.IsValid)`. In that part of the method you register the user. I am wondering if the email address or isAvailable values are missing.

Comment: @James I've updated the method. IsAvailable property is indeed not mentioned, e-mailaddress can be null (although it would be nice if it was the Google e-mailaddress where the person logs in with but this is a concern for later).

Comment: Neither is the email address, have a look in your source control, see when the model was updated and if that ties with when errors started. I would expect the line where you add the user to have something like `User = new User { Name = model.UserName, Email = model.Email, IsAvailable=true };`

Comment: Well if I add values to the properties in that part of the method I still get the same error. It seems that  "User.Identity.IsAuthenticated" has a null value and it cannot be null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `IsAvailable` and `Email` fields not not nullable, then registering new OAuth users will fail with your current code. You need to change

```
user = new User { Name = model.UserName };
```

to something like

```
user = new User { Name = model.UserName, Email = model.Email, IsAvailable = model.IsAvailable };
```

If you have changed your validation, as you suggested, can you confirm the `ExternalLoginConfirmation` view has a field for Email and a hidden field for  `ExternalLoginData`?

(moved this off the comment thread as getting long)

Comment: James! I reverted the files to an older version and now it is working again... It might have been something in the view since I did change some of the lay-out. Thanks for all your help!!! Have some upvotes;)